# hibernate spatial dialect for mysql 8

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, dialect

i use springboot 2.1 and use hibernate last version for orm.
when i want persist my data to db i have this error:

Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

```
@Data
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long Id;

    String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "MultiPolygon")
    MultiPolygon multiPolygon;

}
```

i think problem is in mydialect.

```
server:
port: 8080

logging:
    level:
        com.mousavi007.serverhavadan: debug
spring:
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username:********
    password: ******
    properties:
      mail:
            smtp:
              auth: true
              starttls:
                enable: true
    protocol: smtp
    default-encoding: utf-8

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/havadan
    username: *************
    password: *************
    platform: mysql
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
```

what is spatial dilect for mysql 8 with hibernate last version?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

> org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect

Answer (score 1):

You should use `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect` and use correct geometry types (in this case `org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon`). `@Column` annotation above `MultiPolygon` field is not necessary.

See more: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial